# Get Bash | Laravel Issue | Command Prompt Showing Weird Text

Tags: bash, git-bash, laravel-5.6

So, this started doing this after I did a few customization's of my Get Bash Terminal. Every time I run something like

```
php artisan migrate
```

Or

```
php artisan make:migration Post
```

Or any type of migration or anything to do with php artisan I get some type of text output after the command. Not that this is a huge issue but I would like to know how to make it stop, it seems as if it is outputing the html and query its running. Everything works as it is intended its just when I see it all show up there in my get bash terminal its really annoying.

Like So:
[image: Get Bash - Migration/Get Bash Issue]

Answer (score 1):

I Went Ahead and reinstalled Get Bash and it fixed its self even after I customized it. Weird issue indeed.